# Cross reference of a section that doesn't have a section number

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, templates

I was using [ACM CHI latex template](http://chi2012.acm.org/chi2012archivalformatLaTeX.zip) in which sections do not have section numbers. For example:

> BACKGROUND
>
> SubBackground
>
> SubSubBackground

Now I want to cross reference, but I don't have a section number to refer to:

```
\section{Background}
\label{background}

\subsection{SubBackground}
see \ref{background}
```

> BACKGROUND
>
> SubBackground
>
> see

How do I cross-reference here?

Comment: You said yourself that the sections have no numbers. What number are you expecting to show up?

Comment: Yeah, but then how do I do cross reference? @StephanLehmke

Comment: It is possible to "hijack" the `\label`-`\ref` system using something like `\makeatletter\newcommand{\setref}[1]{\gdef\@currentlabel{#1}}\makeatother` which allows you to use `\section{Background}\setref{Background}\label{background}` and then later issue `See section~\ref{background}`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One possibility is to use the `nameref` package like this:

```
\documentclass{sigchi}

\usepackage{nameref}

\begin{document}

\section{Background}
\label{background}

\subsection{SubBackground}
see section ``\nameref{background}".



\end{document}
```

[image: output]